# Simulate a failed mysql INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Is there a way to simulate a failed `INSERT` query in mysql? Since I'm running PHP/MySQL locally, the return value will always be `TRUE`. Turning of MySQL in xampp doesn't seem to work.

**NOTE:** I may be looking at this the wrong way. Feel free to let me know.

Comment: you could create a test table with a unique key, create a valid record, then insert another record with a duplicate of the key.

Comment: Or try inserting to a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't understand: "the return value" of what? Where does this value come from? Why do you want to simulate a failed insert?

Comment: may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13011787/15721 (its Java, but it may be a workable approach if you put some utility functions between mysql and php so you can intercept things)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of approaches:

- revoke INSERT permission for your database user
- wrap your DB access code into middle layer and simulate failures there

Or if you just need to test INSERTS, create dumb function like:

```
function my_query( $link, string $query ) {
  if( rand() %1 ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return mysqli_query( $link, $query );
  }
}
```

and update your code that INSERTs to call `my_query` instead. Tune your failure conditions and happy testing :)

Comment: Interesting answers. What do you mean by *DB access code into middle layer*? I've never heard of that before.

Comment: See the edited answer first. By `middle layer` I mean any simple class that would be doing DB "talks", so instead of doing i.e. `mysqli_connect()` you do `$db = new MyDatabaseHandler()` (and it connects in constructor or on 1st use) and instead of doing `mysqli_query()` directly you do `$db->query()` and so one. It is basically quite simple task to write such class.