# Make DB fail deterministically for testing

Tags: java, testing

I have a Java application that uses lots of `java.sql.Connection` to a database.

I want to test that, if the database is unavailable, my services return the appropriate error codes (distinguishing between temporary and permanent problems e.g. HTTP 500 and 503).

For testing, my application connects to an embedded, local, in-memory h2 database; the application is not aware of this, only my integration test is.

How can I make writes to the database fail deterministically, e.g. hook into commits and make them throw a custom `SQLException`?  I want a global 'database is unavailable' boolean in the test code that affects all connections and makes my application exercise its reconnect logic.

<sup>(I had started by proxying `Connection` and putting an `if(failFlag) throw new MySimulateFailureException()` in `commit()`; but this didn't catch `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`; before I embark on proxying the `PreparedStatement` too - its a lot of methods! - I'd like to be taught a better way...)</sup>

Comment: this may sound silly, but why not stop the database service? or block the port on a firewall to deny traffic for a bit?

Comment: I usually go the proxy route you outline above. If anyone has a better approach I'd be interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own Java reflection wrapper that intercepts `Connection.commit` and the `PreparedStatement.execute...` methods.

My final code in my 'DBFactory' class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MockFailureException extends SQLException {
    private MockFailureException() {
        super("The database has been deliberately faulted as part of a test-case");
    }
}

private class MockFailureWrapper implements InvocationHandler {

    final Object obj;

    private MockFailureWrapper(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if(dbFailure && ("commit".equals(m.getName()) || m.getName().startsWith("execute")))
            throw new MockFailureException();
        Object result;
        try {
            result = m.invoke(obj, args);
            if(result instanceof PreparedStatement)
                result = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                        result.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                        result.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                        new MockFailureWrapper(result));
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

}


public Connection newConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:"+uuid+";CREATE=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
    return (Connection)java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            connection.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            connection.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            new MockFailureWrapper(connection));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good candidate for using [aspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). With eg. [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) it is supremely easy to pointcut entire packages or just certain methods that you wish to fail - specifically you could have a `before` advice always throwing a `ConnectException` or do something more advanced with the `around` advice.

Cheers,